# Testing for None in if statements

Tags: python

What is the differences between using `if object is None` versus `if not object`?

So while I was doing some coding where I messed up the signals in the QListWidget, where in a selection instance, it is returning me 2 signals, where it returns 2 objects - QListWidgetItem and None.

To address to the None return, I used `if object is None`, but I was told that `if not object` would be better. Even so, it seems that using either of the 2 `if` would still allow me to achieve the same result.

Is there a better case scenario as to when to use either?

Comment: `not object` will be true if object is `0`, `False`, etc.

Comment: Some things are _falsy_ which will trigger on `not` where as only `None` is `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`not object` is true when `object` has any falsey value, such as `0` or `False`.

If you know a priori that the variable contains either a `QListWidgetItem` or `None`, then `None` is the only falsey possibility, so `if not object:` is a simpler way to write the condition.

You just have to be careful about this in other context. Consider a variable that can contain a number or `None`. I've seen many errors due to not considering the possibility that the number might be `0`.

Comment: So I guess it is alright for me to presume that it is a matter of simplification?